# Can't use .value for Text Area in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea

I'm trying to get the value of a text area after the submit button is pressed. However, when I try to use `.value` in my JS file to get the textarea, it doesn't work. Here is my code for my HTML text area and button:

```
<form>
        <textarea type="text" id = "textArea" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And then this is my Javascript code for trying to get the value of the text area. I've set up a listener on the submit button.

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submitButton")
function buttonPressed(){
     var text = document.getElementById("textArea").value (this .value part doesn't show up)
     console.log(text);   
     submit.addEventListener("click", buttonPressed())
}
```

The `.value` part won't work and doesn't show up when I type it. The only thing that does show up is `.nodeValue` How would I get the value of this text area?

I'm a newb at Javascript so any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the whitespace before and after the equal sign here `id = "textArea"` so that you have `id="textArea"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that your button doesn't have attached the event listener because the "addEventListener is inside the function (that is never invoked), I extracted this and the function is invoked now.

```js
const submit = document.getElementById("submitButton");

submit.addEventListener("click", buttonPressed)

function buttonPressed(){
     const text = document.getElementById("textArea").value
     console.log(text);   
}
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea type="text" id = "textArea" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
```